# If I feel that an answer isn't relevant, how do I express that?

Tags: expressions, synonyms, vocabulary, expression-choice

If I feel that an answer isn't relevant to the given question, how can I express it more clearly?

I am not able to come up with an appropriate word to describe what I wish to describe, a few alternatives including examples of usage would be helpful.

Comment: By saying it's irrelevant? Or do you need to get more specific than that?

Comment: I need alternatives and a sentence thats been properly framed.

Comment: Your answer does not address my question. Your answer is not germane to the question. Your answer is not applicable to what I was asking.

Comment: Though the meaning of the idiom is frequently misunderstood, the "correct" use of "begs the question" describes this scenario.

Comment: Although posted as a comment, Brian Hitchcock's suggestions are perfect.

Comment: At first I thought Brian Hitchcock was blgt. If you assume the two posters are identical, it reveals a higher level of meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks Are you sure? Begging the question is a form of circular reasoning. You might be thinking of the more modern "dodging the question" usage of it?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - Originally "begging the question" (sometimes "beggaring the question") meant failing to address the question at all, but (typically) answering a different question.  (Ie, leaving the original question "begging".)  It is misused/misinterpreted to mean answering one question but then raising a new one.  Probably the misuse/misinterpretation is beyond recovery at this point, though.

Comment: @HotLicks If you say so! All I know is wikipedia seems to disagree with you. I don't have a horse in this race so I'm not really debating, but it seems like your understanding might be a little off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically such responses are known as "***non-sequiturs***".

[According to Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur), for example:

> ***non-sequitur*** : a statement that is not connected in a logical or clear way to anything said before it

Comment: How do i use it in a sentence for the given premise
Ps: Google wasn't helpful.